# Getting Nested JSON data using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to get a nested JSON data using VueJS, but I'm having trouble understanding how to do that (I'm new to VueJS). The data is as follows:

```
{
"title": "Editor",
"key": "Editor_one",
"attributes": {
    "holder",
},
"properties": [
    {
        "title": "Date :",
        "attributes": {
            "Path": "0/9",
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "2000/06/17",
        "key": "date_ident",
        "attributes": {
            "Path": "0/10",
        }
    },
    {
        "key": "zero_vector",
        "attributes": {
            "Path": "0/11",
        },
        "properties": [
            {
                "title": "File",
                "attributes": {
                    "Path": "0/11/0",
                },
    },
    {
        "key": "zero_date",
        "attributes": {
            "Path": "0/17",
        },
        "properties": [
            {
                "title": "2000/06/18",
            },
```

My current vueJS code attempt is as follows:

```
<div  v-for="editDate in vectors.slice(0,1)" v-bind:key="editDate.id" class="row-control">
<div v-if="editDate.title = '2000/06/2018'">
  <label style="margin-right: 10px" v-bind="response">{{editDate.title}}</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    v-model="date"
    name="date"
    placeholder="Add Date"
  />
</div>
```

```
async created() {
try {
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/');
  this.vectors = response.data.properties; //assign data from response to 'vectors'
} catch (e){
  console.error(e);
}
```

},

I want to get the data: "title": "2000/06/18" from the key: "zero_date" and bind it to the 'input' tag. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to change this data structure?  I'm confused about why you'd have an array containing objects each with a "key" field, instead of just using an object with those keys (which would let you just do `response.data.properties.zero_date.title` instead of having to search through the array)

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm getting it from an API from someone else who compiled that data, so I don't think I could ( I would since that's how I would go about it and it'll be so much easier to parse). But that's where I'm stuck at right now

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot :)   Taking a closer look at your sample data, I'm not sure whether the various `properties` arrays are supposed to be nested inside each other?  If so, is the array you're looking for at a known location within that tree, or do we need to be doing a search of the whole tree to find it?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes, the various properties arrays are supposed to be nested inside each other (weird, I know). And no, there could be varying amounts of data between the one I'm looking for. I was thinking of having editDate.title = 2000/06/2018 condition and looking at the properties array when it finds it, but I'm not sure how to do that in Vue. I have it vectors.slice(0,1) because it's continuously looping and printing the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does that help? Can `properties` *inside* "zero_date" have more than one item?

```
{
    async created() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/');
            this.vectors = response.data.properties; //assign data from response to 'vectors'
        } catch (e){
            console.error(e);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        zeroDate: {
            get() {
                return this.vectors.find(vector => vector.key === 'zero_date').properties[0].title
            },
            set(newValue) {
                this.vectors.find(vector => vector.key === 'zero_date').properties[0].title = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Properties inside "zero_date" can have more than one item.

Comment: Yes thank you! If I wanted to bind zeroDate()'s returned value to an HTML's input element, would you know how to go about doing that?

Comment: Since "zero_date" can have multiple items inside its `properties`, how do you know, which to use?

Comment: If you want to use it in an input how about this: `<input v-model="zeroDate" />`? Since it's a computed property, I added the setter to my above code.

Comment: Even though "zero_date" has multiple properties, they are always in the same order, so I could parse it as an array for the correct value.

Comment: If it's always at index 0, my could should work :)